# Web3ContractError: The number of arguments is not matching the methods required number. You need to pass 0 arguments

Tags: solidity-0.8.x

**The below is my inbox.test.js file code:**

const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const {Web3} = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const {abi, bytecode} = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
.deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: ['Success!'] })
.send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});

});

describe('Inbox', () => {
it('deploys a contract', () => {
console.log(inbox);
});

```
    it("sets the contract message", async () => {
        await inbox.methods
          .setMessage("test message")
          .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });
    });
```

});

**The error is as follows:**

Inbox
1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract"

0 passing (233ms)
1 failing

1. "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
   Web3ContractError: The number of arguments is not matching the methods required number. You need to pass 0 arguments.

   at encodeMethodABI (node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\encoding.ts:190:9)
   at getSendTxParams (node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\utils.ts:75:26)
   at ContractBuilder._contractMethodDeploySend (node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\contract.ts:1062:29)
   at Object.send (node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\contract.ts:608:17)
   at Context. (test\inbox.test.js:16:13)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

**Please help me with this. This is my first ever smart contract.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error might happen when you invoke `deploy()` with `arguments.length > 0`.
You could try passing the following to the `deploy` method: `{ data: bytecode, arguments: [] }`.

Alternatively, try running your code in Debug mode and inspect where the error is thrown.

Comment: Thankyou sooo much.

Comment: now it shows this error:         "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
     c: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
      at Function.c.fromResults (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\ganache-core.node.cli.js:4:192416)
      at w.processBlock (node_modules\ganache-cli\build\ganache-core.node.cli.js:42:50915)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)